# Hiding the "log" part from `systemctl status` output

Tags: systemd

For a demo, I would like to use `systemctl status` to show the status of a service in human-friendly form, but hiding the log part:

```
### I Want that ####################################

root@bulbizarre:/home/sylvain# systemctl status ssh.service
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-10-09 10:51:59 CEST; 3 days ago
  Process: 1735 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 1729 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1194 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1240 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.9M
      CPU: 80ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1240 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

### But not that ####################################

Oct 09 10:52:26 bulbizarre systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 09 10:52:26 bulbizarre sshd[1240]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 09 10:52:26 bulbizarre sshd[1240]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 09 13:57:52 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failu
Oct 09 13:57:52 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): Authentication failu
Oct 09 13:57:54 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: Failed password for sylvain from 10.129.3
Oct 09 13:57:57 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: pam_ldap(sshd:auth): Authentication failu
Oct 09 13:58:00 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: Failed password for sylvain from 10.129.3
Oct 09 13:58:02 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: Accepted password for sylvain from 10.129
Oct 09 13:58:02 bulbizarre sshd[6966]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened fo
```

Is there some hidden option for that? I know about the `-o` option, but AFAIK there is no "empty" format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How stupid I am! Right after having asked the question I've got an illumination and I tried that:

```
systemctl --lines 0 status ssh.service
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-10-09 10:51:59 CEST; 3 days ago
  Process: 1735 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1729 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1194 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1240 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.9M
      CPU: 80ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1240 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

> ```
>    -n, --lines=
>        When used with status, controls the number of journal lines to show, counting from the
>        most recent ones. Takes a positive integer argument. Defaults to 10.
> ```

It is not obvious from the `man` if this is supposed to work that way (n should be *positive*, not sure if it includes *zero*), anyway setting `--lines=0` remove the log completely (including the empty separator line).

Comment: I’ve submitted a [pull request to systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/10375) to clarify the manpage on this.